# Mahalanobis distance in a matrix form

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

The Mahalanobis distance between two vectors $x_i$ and $y_j$ is given by:

$$d_{ij}(x_i, y_j)^2 = (x_i-y_j)^TQ^{-1}(x_i-y_j)$$

Is there a vectorized way to represent the entries $d_{ij}$ in a matrix form $D$?

Here is my try:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
d_{ij}(x_i, y_j)^2 &= (x_i-y_j)^TQ^{-1}(x_i-y_j) \\
 & = \langle x_i-y_j, Q^{-1}(x_i-y_j) \rangle  \\
 & = \langle x_i, Q^{-1}(x_i-y_j) \rangle - \langle y_j, Q^{-1}(x_i-y_j) \rangle \\
 & = x_i^TQ^{-1}x_i + y_j^TQ^{-1}y_j - 2x_i^TQ^{-1}y_j
\end{split}
\end{equation}

but still have elements entries, not a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two sets of vectors $\{x_i,\,y_j\},\,$ construct two matrices having these vectors as columns
$$\eqalign{
X &= \big[\matrix{x_1&x_2&\ldots&x_m}\big]
 &\in{\mathbb R}^{\ell\times m} \\
Y &= \big[\matrix{y_1&y_2&\ldots&y_n}\big]
 &\in{\mathbb R}^{\ell\times n} \\
}$$
Then the $\,m\times n\,$ matrix of the (squared) Euclidean distances between the vectors can be expressed in terms of either the vectors or the matrices
$$\eqalign{
&E_{ik} = \|x_i-y_k\|^2 &= (x_i-y_k)^T(x_i-y_k) \\
&E = \left(X\odot X\right)^TJ_Y &+ J_X^T\left(Y\odot Y\right) - 2X^TY \\
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product and $(J_X,J_Y)$
are all-ones matrices the same size as $(X,Y)$, respectively.

The Cholesky factorization $\,Q^{-1}=LL^T\;$ can be used to modify the vectors and matrices
$$\eqalign{
x'_i &= L^Tx_i \qquad X'=L^TX \\
y'_k &= L^Ty_k \qquad Y'=L^TY \\
}$$
from which the matrix of (squared) Mahalanobis distances can be calculated.

To calculate the matrix specified in the question, apply the element-wise square root
$$E=D\odot D \quad\implies\quad D=E^{\odot 1/2}$$

Comment: Thank you @greg for answering my question. Can I understand that you meant $Q = RR^T \implies Q^{-1} = (R^{-1})^TR^{-1} = L^TL, \quad where \quad L = R^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: By substituting the mapped matrices in the formula of E we get $$ E = (LX \odot LX)^TJ_Y + J^T_X(LY\odot LY) - 2X^TL^TLY$$, does this formula represent the squared Mahalanobis distances in matrix form?

Comment: I need to calculate the derivatives of E w.r.t X, Y, and L ( instead of Q). I already made an attempt, I will appreciate it if you could check if my derivations are correct, but it will not fit in this comment

Comment: Let $K$ be the Kronecker commutation matrix and define 
the vectors $\,e,x,y = {\rm vec}(E),{\rm vec}(X),{\rm vec}(Y)\,$
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial e}{\partial x}
 &= 2K^T\Big((I_m\otimes J_Y)^T{\rm Diag}({\rm vec}(LX))-(I_m\otimes LY)^T\Big)\Big(I_m\otimes L\Big) \\
\frac{\partial e}{\partial y}
 &= 2\;\Big((I_n\otimes J_X)^T{\rm Diag}({\rm vec}(LY))-(I_n\otimes LX)^T\Big)\Big(I_n\otimes L\Big) \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you again @greg. Your calculation is awesome. If you could give me further details about your derivation it will be great to understand how to get your expressions. I write the trial I made in a separate answer because it didn't fit in the comment. Could you please check if it's correct right there?

Comment: Could you please check the third expression of dE (w.r.t L) and help me to obtain the final expression of dE/dL

Comment: Yup, all three of your new differential calculations are correct. Now apply the vec operator to all the terms to obtain the vector-by-vector gradients.

Comment: Here where I am stuck. I will give it another try.

Comment: This might help: $\;{\rm vec}(A\odot B) = {\rm Diag}({\rm vec}(A))\,{\rm vec}(B)$

Comment: Thank you @greg for the formula, it was very helpful. I updated my calculations. I obtained the same expression of $dE$ w.r.t $Y$ as yours. But not for the two other expressions. Could you please let me know if my differential calculations are correct and the propreties did you use to obtain your expressions.

Comment: Our $X$ derivatives are the same, except I used $dE^T$ on the LHS to clear $dX^T$ on the RHS before starting the differential, and used $K^TK=I$ afterwards. Since you got the other two calculations correct, the $L$ derivative is very likely correct, too.  I didn't check it in detail, but it looks right.

Comment: Your X derivative is more elegant. If the two expressions are similar, which I can't see right now, how could I simplify the mine to get the same expression? e.g., get rid of the second K in the right and multiply the second term in the RHS by (I⊗L) instead of (L⊗I)

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z$ be a matrix whose $i$th column is $x_i - y_i$. Then $Z^\top Q^{-1} Z$ is a matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $d(x_i, y_j)^2$.

Comment: Thanks @angryavian. We can write then: $D = X^TQ^{-1}X -2X^TQ^{-1}Y + Y^TQ^{-1}Y$

Answer (score 1):

The expression given by @greg in his answer allows us to write the following expression $$E = (LX \odot LX)^TJ_Y + J_X^T(LY \odot LY) - 2X^TL^TLY$$

Here is my trial to calculate the derivative of E w.r.t to X, Y, and L.

---

Let $E_1 = (LX \odot LX)^TJ_Y$, $E_2 = J_X^T(LY \odot LY)$, and $E_3= 2X^TL^TLY$

For the $1^{st}$ term we have:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
d(E_1) &= d(LX \odot LX)^TJ_Y + (LX \odot LX)^TdJ_Y\\
& = (2(LX)^T \odot d((LX)^T))J_Y  \\
vec(d(E_1)) & = 2(J_Y \otimes I)(Kvec(LX)\odot ((I\otimes L)Kdx+ (I\otimes X^T)Kdl))\\
&= 2(J_Y \otimes I)(KDiag(vec(LX)))((I \otimes L)Kdx + (X^T \otimes I)Kdl)
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

Then:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \frac{d(vec(E_1))}{d(vec(X))}= 2(J_Y \otimes I)(KDiag(vec(LX)))((I \otimes L)K)\\
& \frac{d(vec(E_1))}{d(vec(Y))}= 0, \\
& \frac{d(vec(E_1))}{d(vec(L))}= 2(J_Y \otimes I)(KDiag(vec(LX)))(X^T \otimes I)K).
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

For the $2^{nd}$ term we have:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
d(E_2) &= d(J_X^T)(LY \odot LY) + J_X^Td(LY \odot LY)\\
& = J_X^T(2LY \odot (dLY + LdY)) \\
& = J_X^T(2LY \odot dLY + 2LY \odot LdY) \\
vec(d(E_2)) &= 2(I \otimes J_X^T)(vec(LY) \odot ((I \otimes L)d(vec(Y)) + (Y^T \otimes I)d(vec(L))) \\
&= 2(I \otimes J_X^T)(Diag(vec(LY))((I \otimes L)dy + (Y^T \otimes I)dl))
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

So
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\frac{d(vec(E_2))}{d(vec(X))}=0, \\
&\frac{d(vec(E_2))}{d(vec(Y))} = 2(I \otimes J_X)^T(Diag(vec(LY))(I \otimes L), \\
&\frac{d(vec(E_2))}{d(vec(L))} = 2(I \otimes J_X)^T(Diag(vec(LY))(Y \otimes I)^T.
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

For the $3^{rd}$ term we have:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
d(E_3) & = 2(d(X^T)L^TLY + X^Td(L^TL)Y + X^TL^TLdY)\\
vec(d(E_3)) & = 2((Y^TL^TL \otimes I)d(vec(X^T) +  \\ & \quad (Y^T \otimes X^T)d(vec(L^TL) + (I \otimes X^TL^TL)d(vec(Y)))  \\
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

where, $ d(vec(L^TL)) = ((L^T \otimes I)K + (I \otimes L^T))d(vec(L))$

Thus:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\frac{d(vec(E_3))}{d(vec(X))}= 2(Y^TL^TL \otimes I)K = 2(LY \otimes I)^T(L \otimes I)K, \\
&\frac{d(vec(E_3))}{d(vec(Y))} = 2(I \otimes X^TL^TL) = 2(I \otimes LX)^T(I \otimes L), \\
&\frac{d(vec(E_3))}{d(vec(L))} = 2(Y^T \otimes X^T)((L^T \otimes I)K + (I \otimes L^T)).
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

Now, by putting the three terms together we obtain

$dE = dE_1 + dE_2 + dE_3$

Holding Y and L constant (i.e. $dY=0$, $dL=0$) yields:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d(vec(E))}{d(vec(X))} & = 2(J_Y \otimes I)(KDiag(vec(LX))((I \otimes L)K) \\
& - 2(LY \otimes I)^T(L \otimes I)K
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Holding X and L constant (i.e. $dX=0$, $dL=0$) yields:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d(vec(E))}{d(vec(Y))} & = 2(I \otimes J_X)^T(Diag(vec(LY))(I \otimes L) -  2(I \otimes LX)^T(I \otimes L) \\
& = 2((I \otimes J_X)^T(Diag(vec(LY)) - (I \otimes LX)^T)(I \otimes L)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Holding X and Y constant (i.e. $dX=0$, $dY=0$) yields:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d(vec(E))}{d(vec(L))} & = 2(J_Y \otimes I)(KDiag(vec(LX))(X^T \otimes I)K) \\
& + 2(I \otimes J_X)^T(Diag(vec(LY))(Y \otimes I)^T \\
& - 2(Y^T \otimes X^T)((L^T \otimes I)K + (I \otimes L^T)). 
\end{split} 
\end{equation}